# AngularJS directive does not work inside Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, directive, ng-upgrade

I have a simple Angular 7 component, that I'm using to normalize a page markup.

*page-title.component.ts*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-page-title',
  templateUrl: './page-title.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page-title.component.css']
})
export class PageTitleComponent {
      @Input() title?: string;
}
```

*page-title.component.html*

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading" *ngIf="title">
    <h3 class="panel-title">{{ title }}</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
</div>
```

I did downgrade this component with `ngUpgrade` library and it works fine, but there is one problem. In my AngularJS app I have the following directive

```
(function () {
  function IsGrantedDirective(AuthManager) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link(scope, elem, attr) {
        if (AuthManager.isGranted(attr.isGranted)) {
          return;
        }
        console.log("I'm called");
        elem.remove();
      },
    };
  }

  angular
    .module('my.common')
    .directive('isGranted', IsGrantedDirective);
}());
```

The directive is pretty simple, but when I'm using it somewhere inside Angular `my-page-title` component:

```
<my-page-title>
    <div is-granted="role">Whatever</div>
</my-page-title>
```

It does not work:

1. `console.log("I'm called")` works
2. there are no errors in console
3. the `div` is being displayed anyway

It seems that `elem.remove()` does not take any affect inside Angular component, any ideas, please?

P.S. it seems to be working if a put another bare `div` around an element with the attribute

```
 <my-page-title>
     <div> // <----
         <div is-granted="role">Whatever</div>
     </div>
 </my-page-title>
```